# Determine Type of data in datagrid column

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a datagrid that is bound using XAML to specific properties of a class. Is there a way programmatically to determine what Type is attached to that column in the C# code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each [column definition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.grid.columndefinitions%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) of the grid has a [DependencyObjectType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencyobject.dependencyobjecttype) property which is a wrapper for the underlying Clr type.